# equivalent of ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance in Autofac

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac

Are there any equivalent for following method from **Microsoft Dependency Injection** in **Autofac**.

ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(serviceProvider)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct analog for `ActivatorUtilities` in Autofac. But you have options.

You can directly resolve things that are registered (service location) - `lifetimeScope.Resolve<T>()`

If you need to resolve any type at all rather than only things you've registered, [`AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource`](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/registration-sources.html) can help.

You can inject properties into constructed objects - `lifetimeScope.InjectProperties(obj)`

Or, if you really need `ActivatorUtilities`, you can use the `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection` package to [create a Microsoft container backed by Autofac](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/netcore.html) and use the utility methods directly.

Comment: Nice answer but I wanted to highlight the potentially misleading section on the link to using `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection`: you are not "creating a Microsoft container backed by Autofac", but "creating an Autofac container adapted to the Microsoft interface". It really is not a "Microsoft container".